# How does one show that sets are separated in R2?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that two sets C and D are separated if $C\cap\overline{D}$ and $D\cap\overline{C}$  are empty. I am not certain how this works in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$C$ is the set {$(x,y)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: y=$sin(1/x$), $x > 0$}.

$D$ is the set {$(x,y)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: $x=0$}.

For $C$, $x \in$ $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ and $y \in [-1,1]$.  $D$ is the y-axis.

$D$ is closed with no interior point in  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. As far as I can tell, it does not intersect $C$ because $C$ does not contain $(0,0)$.

But I am not sure what to make of whether $C$ is open or closed. If it were open, How would I close it?

Answer (score 1):

$C$ is neither open nor closed. Its closure is $$C\cup\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x=0,|y|\le 1\bigr\}.$$ As such, $C$ and $D$ are not separated.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or is that supposed to be a greater than or equal to symbol?  (Thank you, Cameron).

Comment: It is not a typo. Put another way, to close $C,$ we must include the interval $[-1,1]$ on the $y$ axis. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I guess I do not see why that interval isn't already included in C.

Comment: This is because by definition, for every $(x,y)\in C,$ we have that $x>0.$ Consequently, no point of $C$ is on the $y$-axis.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, I appreciate your taking the time to help.

Comment: You're very welcome!